# Are applications written for iPhone binary compatible with iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, compatibility, ipod-touch

Given that for instance no sms APIs are invoked. Say I would want to port my 'notepad' app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.
So long as your application does not take advantage of iPhone-specific features (SMS is a great example), you should be able to run it on OS-compatible iPhone and iPod Touch devices.